# Laravel custom validation rule. How to add possibility for passing rule with a string representation instead of using class name?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

What do I mean:

As it's shown at documentation:

```
...
'field' => [
 'required',
 'numeric',
 new MyCustomRule
],
...
```

But what if I want to pass it in one string and with some arguments||options signature (as it's implemented with default "exists" rule where i can optionally pass connection, table, field, column and so on)?

```
...
'field' => 'required|numeric|my_rule:param1.param2,option1,option2',
...
```

Where should i define signature? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend your validator inside `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`

E.g:

```
Validator::extend('rule', function (string $attribute, string $value, array $parameters) {
    dump($attribute, $value, $parameters);

    return $attribute == $value;
});
```

See a working example [here](https://github.com/erdemkeren/tr-nat-id-num-validator/blob/master/src/TrNatIdNumValidationServiceProvider.php).

Comment: It is not a must. You can use the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider`. Doing so; you can make sure that your rule will be ready before your controller or request classes.

Comment: Thank you so much!